# Value in list is not updated by thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried to update value in a list by thread, 
but it does not working for me.

Below is my code, please point what i am wrong.
Thanks.

```
// List of Integer values
public static volatile ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public static void main(String... args) {
    intList.add(11);

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Loop and increase value of a list of integer
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                synchronized (this) {
                    for (Integer item : intList) {
                        System.out.print("thread 1: " + item);
                        item++; //increase value
                        System.out.print(" -> " + item + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread1.start();
}
```

Output: 
*thread 1: 11 -> 12*
*thread 1: 11 -> 12*
*thread 1: 11 -> 12*
*thread 1: 11 -> 12*
*thread 1: 11 -> 12*
=> value is not changed when the loop start, it still 11 every time of beginning of loop. 
What's wrong?

Comment: You never actually change item value. Integers are immutable.

Comment: Use ListIterator instead of foreach loop, and call set() method for each item.

Comment: Thanks @esin88: It worked if I use intList.set(i, intList.get(i) + 1);

Comment: You're welcome :) But be careful with `intList.set(i, intList.get(i) + 1)`. It works good with `ArrayList`, but is incredibly slow with `LinkedList`. With `LinkedList` (or if you're not sure about list type) it's better to use `ListIterator`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line of code:

```
item++; //increase value
```

The JVM is applying autoboxing to object item, creating an int primitive value, augmenting it by 1, and then creating a new Integer Object. So, you are not modifying the object inside your list.